# Is this limit equal to $g'(f(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $(a,b), (c,d) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $(a,b) \xrightarrow{f} (c,d) \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\exists x\in (a,b)$, where $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(x)$.

Now we shall define a function as following:

Let $\varphi_{x}:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by:
$$\varphi_{x}(t) = \frac{g(f(t))-g(f(x))}{f(t)-f(x)}$$
Where $D = \{t\in(a,b)\text{ | }f(t) \neq f(x) \}$

Is:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow x}\varphi_x(t) = g'(f(x))$$

It feels trivially true but when actually proving it, it turned out to be quite difficult. Maybe I am being dumb and focusing too much on pedantics to find a clear proof.

I obviously know:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow f(x)} \frac{g(h)-g(f(x))}{h-f(x)} = g'(f(x))$$
But this isn't quite the same as $\lim_{t\rightarrow x}\varphi_x(t) = g'(f(x))$

Any help, or am I just being dumb lol?

Comment: it's exactly that... set $h=f(t)$ and when $t\to x$, the $h\to f(x)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. You can see it with an involved $\epsilon-\delta$ argument but it is often easier to prove such results in $\mathbb R$ using sequential criteria. Here is the sequential criterion for differentiability:

A function $\xi : (u, v) \to \mathbb R$ (where $u < v \in \mathbb R$) is differentiable at $w \in (u, v)$ with derivative $L$ iff for every sequence $(w_n)_{n = 1}^\infty \subset (u, v)$ s.t. $w_n \neq w$ and $w_n \to w$, the ratio $\frac{\xi(w_n) - \xi(w)}{w_n - w} \to L$.

In fact, real continuity and indeed real function limits in general can be entirely characterized with similar sequential criteria.

Thus in your case, take any sequence $(t_n)_{n = 1}^\infty \subset D$ s.t. $t_n \to x$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, it is certainly continuous at $x$ too. So by the applying the sequential criterion for continuity to $(t_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ and $f$, the sequence $(f(t_n))_{n = 1}^\infty$ converges to $f(x)$. But $g$ is differentiable at $f(x)$. So now applying the sequential criterion for differentiability to $(f(t_n))_{n = 1}^\infty$ and $g$, we see that
$$
\varphi_x(t_n) = \frac{g(f(t_n)) - g(f(x))}{f(t_n) - f(x)} \to g'(f(x))
$$ Since this was true for every sequence $(t_n)_{n = 1}^\infty \subset D$, by using the sequential criterion for limits this time in the reverse direction, we conclude that $\lim_{t \to x; t \in D }\varphi_x(t)$ exists and is equal to $g'(f(x))$.

Comment: This answer brought a tear to my eye, truly beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: @PHHerman Glad to be of help